# What is the purpose of machine learning? Can we use something else to predict the future data instead of machine learning method?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

I started studying machine learning in R and I was just curious...

We are trying to find the model with good accuracy by using train and test data for prediction... but instead of using machine learning process, can't we predict the future with Regression model?

I just want to know how machine learning can change the results... will the plot of machine learning model be different with Regression model plot?

I'm just curious...

Comment: Depending on who you ask, many would say regression (I assume you mean OLS regression) is itself in fact a (simple) machine learning tool. You can do prediction with any statistical model. Whether OLS should be used depends on the data. Whether you call it machine learning or not often depends on your goals. As the question is posed now, it may end up being closed as too broad.

Comment: If you are looking for a more black and white explaination, take a look at these links:

 - [ML vs Predictive Modeling](https://www.educba.com/machine-learning-vs-predictive-modelling/)
 - [ML vs. Statistical Modeling](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/07/difference-machine-learning-statistical-modeling/)
 - [Regression vs. ML](https://medium.com/quick-code/regression-versus-classification-machine-learning-whats-the-difference-345c56dd15f7)

Answer (score 2):

Regression models are part of Machine learning methods. You can implement a regression model, train it (meaning that the algorithm computes the coefficients, as for a basic regression) and then test it on your test set.

Comment: Actually Machine Learning only describes a procedure of finding the 'best' model of one class (f.i. regression, binary discrimination, knn...) where 'best' means the one which minimizes the Mean squared error (or another norm) on your test dataset

Comment: So if I find the best model and wants to predict the future, do I just have to plot the graph with predict()?